# Webpack Loader with Dynamic Query

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a Webpack loader set up for SVG files in my webpack config, and it looks like this

```
const SVGO_CONFIG = JSON.stringify({
  plugins: [
    {removeTitle: true},
  ],
});

const SVG_LOADER = {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'babel!svg-react!svgo?' + SVGO_CONFIG,
};
```

This allows me to `import` svg files as if they were react components like so

```
import Icon from 'src/images/icon.svg';
```

But in certain cases, I'd like to be able to tell the `svgo-loader` to strip `fill` and `stroke` attributes from the files. I can do this by setting another plugin in the config

```
const SVGO_CONFIG = JSON.stringify({
  plugins: [
    {removeTitle: true},
    {removeAttrs: {attrs: "(fill|stroke)"}},
  ],
});
```

But this would apply to all the svg files I import. Is there a simple way to flag an import statement to slightly modify the config like so?

```
import TransparentIcon from 'src/images/icon.svg?removeFill`;
```

My half-solution is to save the file with an extra extension (or in a different folder), but this would mean I wouldn't get the option to import it with or without stripping the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Use the regex of the `test` attribute in two separate SVG loaders, like so:

   ```
   const SVGO_CONFIG = JSON.stringify({
     plugins: [
       {removeTitle: true},
     ],
   });

   const SVG_LOADER = {
     test: /\.svg$/,
     loader: 'babel!svg-react!svgo?' + SVGO_CONFIG,
   };

   const SVGO_CONFIG_REMOVE_FILL = JSON.stringify({
     plugins: [
       {removeTitle: true},
       {removeAttrs: {attrs: "(fill|stroke)"}},
     ],
   });

   const SVG_LOADER_REMOVE_FILL = {
     test: /\.svg\?removeFill$/,
     loader: 'babel!svg-react!svgo?' + SVGO_CONFIG_REMOVE_FILL,
   };
   ```
2. You could write your own loader to adjust the query string. (This is probably over-engineering):

   ```
   module.exports = function(content) {
     return content;
   };
   module.exports.pitch = function(remainingRequest, precedingRequest, data) {
     var i;
     var len = this.loaders.length;
     var loader;
     if (this.resourceQuery === '?removeFill') {
       for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         loader = this.loaders[i];
         if (loader.query === '?{"plugins":[{"removeTitle":true}]}') {
           loader.query = '?' + JSON.stringify({
             plugins: [
               {removeTitle: true},
               {removeAttrs: {attrs: "(fill|stroke)"}},
             ],
           });
         }
       }
     }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `include` for this purpose. Example:

```
const SVG_LOADER = {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'babel!svg-react!svgo?' + SVGO_CONFIG,
  include: [path.join(__dirname, 'svgs/demo.svg', ...]
};
```

You would need two separate rules like these. You should make sure their `include`s don't overlap as otherwise it will execute both. One neat way to solve this problem is to split your svgs per directories and point to those.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Except i need to check svg file name with its addition. Is it possible to do it like this  ?                                                                                                                                                          
        test: /.*multicolor\.svg$/   ??

Comment: @palyxk If you need a more complicated test that's easy to understand, please use a function. That's a lot easier to maintain than a complex regexp.

Comment: actually to use exclude was correct idea i just had mess in paths